# Invoke-ASCmd cmdlet output to e-mail body

Tags: powershell, azure-analysis-services

I am a newbie in Powershell... Hope you can help me.
I have a script that is refreshing the database (tabular model) on Azure Analysis Services. The script is supposed to refresh all the tables that we have in the model, but not at once, so we would like to refresh all the dimension tables in parallel first and then all the fact tables in parallel as a second step.

To do that we are using the `Invoke-ASCmd` cmdlet which is calling the code hardcoded in the variable `$DataLoad` and it looks like this:

```
Invoke-ASCmd -Server $AASServerAddress -Query $DataLoad -Credential $AzureCred -OutVariable out
```

The output is a xml string, if everything with the refresh went smooth it looks like this:

```
<return xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
    <root xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:empty"></root>
</return>
```

and if there was a problem it is giving me the error details. 
After the script is finished, it is sending the e-mail message to a few people with the information that the script is finished in the body.

What I would like to have is the output of my `Invoke-ASCmd` to the e-mail body. I was trying to play with the `OutVariable` and `ToString()`, but it is giving me the result `"System.Collections.ArrayList"` in the body and as a `Write-Output`.

On the other hand, I was just trying to put my `$out` variable to the body, but it didn't come up in the e-mail, but when I do a `Write-Output $out` - it is displayed in the output for the script.

Any chance to get that working without saving the xml file to Azure Storage and attach it as a attachment to the mail? We really would like to have it in the body of e-mail.

EDIT: I tried to convert the System.Collections.ArrayList, which I am getting from the `-OutVariable out`, to string by using various methods like:

1. "Convert" `$out` to `$($out)`
2. Created the `$conv = $out.ToString()`
3. Tried to use `| Out-String` with the `Invoke-ASCmd` cmdlet and with the `$Message.Body` variable

Any of the above didn't work. The e-mail body is empty. I've seen some articles that the `OutVariable` command is giving the array list instead of string result in Powershell versions less than 6. The PS version on the Azure Analysis Services is 5.1 and it, probably, cannot be updated due to the compatibility issues.

Thank you in advance,
Bartek

Comment: Just try surrounding it with $() in the body

Answer (score 0):

```
[xml]$Result = Invoke-ASCmd –InputFile $file -Server $Server
$emailmsg = $Result.return.root.Messages.Error.description

$emailmsg'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).